# need help with understanding \overunderbraces syntax

Tags: underbrace, overbrace

Here's an example from the `oubraces` package documentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{oubraces}
\begin{document}
\[
  \overunderbraces{&\br{2}{x}& &\br{2}{y}}%
  {a + b +&c + d +&e + f&+&g + h&+ i + j&+ k + l + m}%
  {& &\br{3}{z}}
  = \pi r^2
\]
\end{document}
```

I can't seem to understand the usage of `&`'s around `\br` commands.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making your code compilable and posting a screenshot (same as in the user guide of the `oubraces` package).

Comment: It would appear that you've already tried to consult the user guide of the `oubraces` package. Please indicate where you the explanation no longer worked for you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be explained in there.

Answer (score 3):

- Maybe this helps.
- The equation is divided into parts by using `&` - same as for tables.
- You then refer to the parts in the argument of the `\overunderbraces` command.
- `\overunderbraces{ & \br{1}{+ \mathrm{middle}} & }` means that the brace starts at the 2nd part (no command before the first `&`).
- `\br{1}{+ \mathrm{middle}}` means that the brace should span over `1` part.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622383

\usepackage{oubraces}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table Example.}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
\hline
 left & middle & right \\ 
 left & middle & right \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{equation}
\overunderbraces{ & \br{1}{+ \mathrm{middle}} & }%
{\mathrm{left} & + \mathrm{middle} & + \mathrm{right}}%
{& & \br{1}{+ \mathrm{right}}}
= \mathrm{result}  
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\overunderbraces{&\br{2}{x}& &\br{2}{y}}%
{a + b +&c + d +&e + f&+&g + h&+ i + j&+ k + l + m}%
{& &\br{3}{z}}
= \pi r^2  
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: still processing, but thanks ;)